# My delete statement is not working (using oracle 11g)

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

My delete statement is not working i am trying to delete duplicate row if user have entered more than one product_id and user_id but the delete is not working at all.

I tried entering one row multiple time and `hasNext` returns true, goes over if but doesn't execute delete and alert

Code:

```
<%-- 
    Document   : cart
    Created on : Apr 24, 2020, 3:43:01 PM
    Author     : user
--%>

<%@page import="java.sql.CallableStatement"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.SQLException"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.ResultSet"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.DriverManager"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.Statement"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.Connection"%>
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>JSP Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <%

            String username=(String)session.getAttribute("username");
            String product_id=request.getParameter("id");
            Connection con=null;
            Statement stmt=null;
            Statement stmt1=null;
            Statement stmt2=null;
            try{
                Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver");
                con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE","admin","admin");
            }
            catch(ClassNotFoundException e){
                System.out.println("Class not found :"+e.getMessage());
            }
            try{
                int user_id=0;
                stmt=con.createStatement();
                stmt1=con.createStatement();
                stmt2=con.createStatement();
                //check for duplicate rows to avoid user adding to cart the same item again.
                ResultSet rs=stmt.executeQuery("SELECT user_id FROM users where user_name='"+username+"'");
                while(rs.next()){
                    user_id=Integer.valueOf(rs.getString(1));
                    System.out.println(user_id);

                }
                    stmt1.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO transaction (user_id,product_id) values('"+user_id+"','"+product_id+"')");
                    ResultSet rs_check=stmt.executeQuery("SELECT '"+user_id+"','"+product_id+"', COUNT(*) occurences from transaction GROUP BY '"+user_id+"','"+product_id+"' HAVING COUNT(*) > 1 ");
                    //check for duplicate rows after insert and then delete that row
                    System.out.println(rs_check.next());//1)false
                    boolean hasNext=rs_check.next();
                    if(hasNext){
                        //stmt2.executeUpdate("delete from transaction where user_id='"+user_id+"' and product_id='"+product_id+"'");
                        CallableStatement ctmt=con.prepareCall("{call delete_dup(?,?)}");  
                        ctmt.setInt(1,user_id);  
                        ctmt.setInt(2,Integer.valueOf(product_id));  
                        ctmt.execute();  
                        %><script>alert("you have added the item before?");</script><%
                    }
            }
            catch(SQLException e){
                System.out.println("SQL Exception: "+e.getMessage());
            }

        %>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please don't write SQL code inside an HTML page, this is so wrong in so many levels :(

Comment: @ÓscarLópez I have coded it in JSP

Comment: That's no excuse, in a well-written JSP the Java code resides in its own classes in separate files, and in the JSP you just use tags to display the results. The way you're currently writing it, it's a recipe for disaster, it'll become unmaintainable quite fast. To make things worse, you're mixing HTML, JSP, JavaScript, Java and SQL all in the same file.

Comment: @ÓscarLópez In JSP you can write in html and even you can embed javascript and is used to connect to database by java code so my code is correct

Comment: The fact that you _can_ doesn't mean that you _should_. I hope that you'll learn that there are better ways to architect an application. This is not "correct", by the way. It might work, but it's not the proper way to build software.

Comment: @ÓscarLópez then please tell me how should i do it according to your way?

Comment: Start by reading about architecture, separation of concerns, design patterns and best practices. Here's a good starting point: http://www.corej2eepatterns.com

Comment: And BTW, it's not "my way", it's the industry standard, most people expect to have an application designed and built in a certain way, you should follow the established patterns and best practices to be a successful professional. And one of the most basic ones is: you don't put Java and HTML code in the same file. And you don't mix database code and presentation code in the same file.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add a commit after the insert to check if this works like :
`con.commit();`

If this solve the problem you have to set : `con.setAutoCommit(true);`, if you don't want to use Oracle commit/rollback feature.